# Does a Restore Point Persist after Flashback/Point-in-time?

Tags: oracle, recovery, flashback, restore-points, point-in-time-recovery

If I have created a restore point `my_restore_point`

```
create restore point my_restore_point;
```

then flashback to this restore_point

```
flashback database to restore point my_restore_point;
```

1. Will `my_restore_point` still exist?

```
select * from v$restore_point where name = 'MY_RESTORE_POINT';
```

2. Will `my_restore_point` still exist if I flashback to the restore point's SCN?

```
variable my_scn number
exec select scn into :my_scn from v$restore_point where name = 'MY_RESTORE_POINT'
flashback database to scn :my_scn;
```

3. Will `my_restore_point` still exist if I flashback to **before** the restore point's SCN?

```
flashback database to before scn :my_scn;
```

4. Will `my_restore_point` still exist if I perform an RMAN point-in-time recovery `UNTIL SCN x`, where `x` is the value in `:my_scn`?

If I had an environment in which to test this I would attempt these tests myself, so my advanced gratitude to this community for the assist.

Using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore points need to be available during MOUNT phase, so they are not like tables etc that are "rewound" during a flashback, eg

```
SQL> create restore point rp1 guarantee flashback database;

Restore point created.

SQL> create table t1 ( x int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create restore point rp2 guarantee flashback database;

Restore point created.

SQL> create table t2 ( x int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select name, scn from v$restore_point;

NAME                                            SCN
------------------------------ --------------------
RP1                                  16331017175532
RP2                                  16331017175547

SQL>
SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 3221224152 bytes
Fixed Size                  9304792 bytes
Variable Size            2801795072 bytes
Database Buffers          385875968 bytes
Redo Buffers               24248320 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL>
SQL> flashback database to restore point rp2;

Flashback complete.

SQL> select name, scn from v$restore_point;

NAME                                            SCN
------------------------------ --------------------
RP1                                  16331017175532
RP2                                  16331017175547

SQL>
SQL> flashback database to restore point rp1;

Flashback complete.

SQL> select name, scn from v$restore_point;

NAME                                            SCN
------------------------------ --------------------
RP1                                  16331017175532
RP2                                  16331017175547
```